# How to give an array C# property a default value?

Tags: c#

So I know with normal properties you can give it a default value eg.

```
public int someMethod { get; } = 1;
```

So my question is it possible to do the same with an array property?

```
public int[] someMethod {get; } = ??
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can do it with an array, or any other data type. And what you type in is exactly the same as if it was some local variable.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks! That helped me. I just wasn't sure how to initialise the array without knowing the length of the array but the empty method worked a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] someMethod {get; } = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, ... };
```

Comment: What if I don't know the length of the array?

Comment: You can't initialize an array without knowing the length of it.

Comment: @gunr2171 you are implicitly specifying the length of the array when you are initializing the default values. https://dotnetfiddle.net/GaWNxE

Comment: Yeah, you either type a number in the square brackets, or you have a set number of elements in the curly braces. Either way, you have to know the length of the array when you initialize it.

Comment: If you don't know the length, then List<T> is a better choice.
[Create List at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793000/create-listint-with-values-at-compile-time)